# Is a temp table really necessary in this SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In taking a look at some existing sprocs in a project I was brought into, I am seeing things like this:

```
declare @tmpTable Table (
    ID bigint,
    patientID   uniqueidentifier,
    resultDate  datetime,
    resultParameter nvarchar(50),
    resultValue decimal(18, 6),
    resultUnit  nvarchar(50),
    pos smallint,
    minpos smallint,
    maxpos smallint
)

if (@patientID is not null)
    begin
        declare @minpos smallint = 0;
        declare @maxpos smallint = 0;

        select 
            @minpos = min(a.pos),
            @maxpos = max(a.pos)
        from tbl_patientBiometricResults a (nolock)
        where a.patientID = @patientID

        insert into @tmpTable
        (
            ID,
            patientID,
            resultDate,
            resultParameter,
            resultValue,
            resultUnit,
            pos,
            minpos,
            maxpos
        )
        select 
            a.ID, 
            a.patientID,
            a.resultDate,
            a.resultParameter,
            a.resultValue,
            a.resultUnit,
            a.pos,
            @minpos,
            @maxpos
        from tbl_patientBiometricResults a (nolock)
        where a.patientID = @patientID

    end

select * from @tmpTable order by pos;
```

The thing that stands out for me here is that they are using temp tables, and I really don't see the benefit in this for this type of sproc.  There are no new fields added in the temp table (no combination of tables), only a subset of the fields available  in the `tbl_patientBiometricResults` table.

Is there a benefit to using a temp table in this case?

---

Comment: This is a table variable, not a temp table. From what I see here there is no need for this variable. Also, I would get rid of the NOLOCK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean mentioned in a comment, there are no benefits to using your table variable. You could easily rewrite the query in a simpler format like so:

```
IF (@patientID is not null)
BEGIN
    SELECT  ID, 
            patientID,
            resultDate,
            resultParameter,
            resultValue,
            resultUnit,
            pos,
            minPos, --MIN(pos) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) /*Alternative for SQL 2012+. No need for CROSS APPLY*/
            maxPos  --MAX(pos) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
    FROM tbl_patientBiometricResults
    CROSS APPLY(
                    SELECT  MIN(pos) minPos,
                            MAX(pos) maxPos
                    FROM    tbl_patientBiometricResults
                    WHERE   patientID = @patientID
                )
    WHERE patientID = @patientID
    ORDER BY pos;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it does seem overkill out of context, but I have found that under certain scenarios for example involving SSIS you may need to construct a table variable like this in order for the SSIS package to recognize the metadata the stored procedure returns. Not sure if that matters in your case though!